# Magento REST API Post Product and Category without "Sorting" parameter

Tags: magento2, rest-api

I need to POST products with their category number, but without their sorting because I dont want to change the sorting via API.

```
{"product": {
    "id": 1234,
    "sku": "2345",
    "name": "Nice Product",
    "extension_attributes": {
        "website_ids": [1],
        "category_links": [{
            "position": 11,
            "category_id": "123"
        }]
    }}
}
```

As soon as I take out the sorting position I get an error.

So, how can I post a product including the Category but without changing its sorting within one call?

Comment: Did you try leaving it blank?

Comment: Blank does not work its an INT but I also tested NULL

Comment: It have INT class, have you tried "position": 0

Comment: Refer catalogProductRepositoryV1 https://devdocs.magento.com/swagger/index_20.html

Comment: I know that well, but it does not help. I am not able to POST a Products with Category without changing its sorting.

Comment: can I clarify? if your product gets assigned to a category and you don't want to assign a sorting position to it, then you are happy for this product to go down at the bottom of the products assigned to this category, right? If so, just assign a position of 99999 and that should do what you are after? if not, magento does need a position and that is not only the API but it is the database so you will need to come up with a business rule telling what the sorting is.. if none of this applies, I am missing the point.