# Magento 2 REST API Product delete Category entry

Tags: magento2, rest-api

Updating a product with REST API with POST gives me a problem wenn I want to delete the category assignment

For example the product online is assignet into 3 categories and now I want it into 2 categories only.

So my POST would be like:

```
   {"product": {
        "id": 1234,
        "sku": "2345",
        "name": "Nice Product",
        "extension_attributes": {
            "website_ids": [1],
            "category_links": [{
                "position": 1,
                "category_id": "10"
            },
{
                "position": 2,
                "category_id": "11"
            }]
        }}
    }
```

But after this it still has assigment into 3 categories, its not deleeting the 3rd.

Btw. I have a simular question:
[Magento REST API Post Product and Category without "Sorting" parameter](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/249023/magento-rest-api-post-product-and-category-without-sorting-parameter)

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to find any solution to Update the Category Entry within one POST.
So the only solution was to delete them and in another POST to write the Update.

To delete Categorys Post this:

```
   {"product": {
        "id": 1234,
        "sku": "2345",
        "name": "Nice Product",
        "extension_attributes": {
            "website_ids": [1],
            "category_links": []
        }}
    }
```

Comment: this does not work

Answer (score 0):

This answer is late, but maybe it'll help someone else. I haven't found a way to change categories, but just learned that saving the product with category_links set to null, not an empty array, will remove all of them.

Answer (score 0):

Using rest API, you can delete the category with the endpoint:
categories/{categoryId}/products/{sku}
and http method DELETE
Replace {categoryId} for the numeric category ID and replace {sku} for the alphanumeric sku.

A code example, not PHP, but in case it helps:

```
&SdtMagentoContext.HttpMethod = HttpMethod.Delete
&SdtMagentoContext.Url = 'categories/{categoryId}/products/{sku}'
&SdtMagentoContext.Url = &SdtMagentoContext.Url.Replace('{categoryId}', StyCatECde.ToString().Trim())
&SdtMagentoContext.Url = &SdtMagentoContext.Url.Replace('{sku}', &SdtMagentoConfigurable.product.sku.Trim())
&SdtMagentoContext.PgmName = &Pgmname
PMagentoRestExec.Call(&SdtContext, &SdtMagentoContext)
```